# change values in dataframe according to column name with dplyr?

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr, names

My problem seemed really easy but can't figure out an easy solution.
I have a value for all categorical variables in my dataset which is "missing".
In order join results later on with a function of myown I need this value to be unique so what I want, is to change the value "missing" by "missing (var_name)".

I first tried something like :

```r
data %>% mutate(across(where(is.character),
                       ~ replace(., . == "missing", paste("missing", SOMETHING(.)))))
```

This doesn't quite work since I miss this `SOMETHING` function to access the column name throughout the `across` statement just using the "." parameter...

The other solution I tried is using

```r
purrr:imap(data %>% select(where(is.character)),
           ~ replace(.x, .x == "missing", paste("missing", .y))))
```

This is close to what I want but then I have trouble reinserting easily and computationnaly effeciently the `purrr:imap` output into my initial dataframe instead of the initial character columns.

I think I need some break and/or some help to see clearer because I am kind of tired fighting with something which appear to be so simple...

I would rather use the `dplyr`solution but the `purrr` one is ok. Actually, whatever works fine and quick (just so you know, I have more than 600 cols et 150,000 rows)

Any help or advice is welcome !

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Example Data***

```
df <- data.frame(var.X = c("a", "missing", "a"),
                 var.Y = c("b", "b", "missing"),
                 var.Z = c("missing", "missing", "c"))

#     var.X   var.Y   var.Z
# 1       a       b missing
# 2 missing       b missing
# 3       a missing       c
```

By `dplyr`, you can use `cur_column()` in `across()`. From `?context`:

> cur_column() gives the name of the current column (in across() only).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character),
                ~ recode(.x, missing = paste0("missing(", cur_column(), ")"))))

#            var.X          var.Y          var.Z
# 1              a              b missing(var.Z)
# 2 missing(var.X)              b missing(var.Z)
# 3              a missing(var.Y)              c
```

or

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character),
                ~ recode(.x, missing = sprintf("missing(%s)", cur_column()))))
```

Comment: Thanks @Darren ! That's exactely what I was looking !